# Weird compile error involving type parameters with a wildcard

Tags: scala, generics, wildcard, covariance

I am sorry, I can't formulate the title (or the question for that matter) to be any more informative than this, because I have no idea what is going on here. Why doesn't this code compile:

```
 class Foo
 class Bar[+R <: Foo] { def bar = "bar" }
 class Bak(val b: Bar[_])
 val bak = new Bak(new Bar[Foo])
 bak.b.bar // fine
 println(bak.b) // fine
 bak.b  // oops!
 ^^^ type arguments [Any] do not conform to class Bar's type parameter bounds [+R <: Foo]
```

What is this? Why can I use the variable, but not assign it it a val??? 
Does it make sense to anyone?

Comment: You can bound the wildcard `class Bak(val b: Bar[_ <: Foo])`, though I don't know why it waits for the error. Even setting it to a wildcard val doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @MichaelZajac well, yeah ... I can also just do `class Bak(val v: Bar[Foo])` which would be, pretty much the same thing because of covariance. I think, the only reason to use wildcard in this case is brevity - so that one wouldn't have to spell out the `Foo` .. but having to write the boundary explicitly defeats that purpose :(

Comment: `Bar[_]` defaults to `Bar[_  <: Any]` according to the SLS 3.10 placeholder syntax. It's just weird that the error only manifests when being assigned to a value.

Answer (score 0):

**Covariant** with **Wildcard** type, the compiler will set the `res`'s container type to `Any`, like:

```
scala> val l: List[_] = List(123)
l: List[_] = List(123)
scala> l
res1: List[Any] = List(123)
scala> :type l
List[Any]
```

As the above code,  `List` container type is `_`, and since `List` is **covariant**, so the compiler will set `l`'s `res` type to `List[Any]`.

And as your code snippet `R` is **upperbound** to `Foo`, so there will be a conflict between `Foo` with `Any`:

```
val res: Bar[Any] = bak.b //+R <: Foo
```

so this **compile error** is throwed, in **repl** it will auto assign `bak.b` to a temp **res** variable.

Comment: Right, so the question is, why it sets it to `Any` rather than `Foo` in this case. Is this a bug?